# gcp cloud functions handle in batches

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm writing a gcp cloud function and is there a feature to handle a batch of messages put on a pub/sub topic.  I mean a single run of the cloud function can handle around 10-30 messages put on the queue.  From the examples I have seen the cloud function gets invoked for each message.  But in AWS I have seen the option where you can batch multiple messages into one Lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the traditional method Cloud functions + PubSub receiving messages via push, you won't be able to work with batches since every event will trigger the function.

You could perhaps create a different mechanism (trigger) for example a Cloud Scheduler to trigger the cloud function and pull all messages in the queue (pull mechanism): https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull